# How to use img2pdf as module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdf-generation, jpeg

I'm building a tiny Python 2.7.9 script that takes a list of JPEG images as an input and outputs a PDF file. I'm googling for hours but can't find a solution:

- I tried [pypdf](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf), but it says I don't have PIL installed although i have.
- I tried [Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com), but the page size is bigger than the image itself and I couldn't find a way to fix it. I also find it hard...
- I tried [img2pdf](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf), but couldn't understand how to use it

I'm really tired of all these libraries, and I'm looking for a **good** solution.
Good means:

- As pythonic as possible
- fit page size to image size
- Support big amount of images (maybe even 500)
- Easy enough

If you can help with with the modules I already tried/code examples it would be awesome.
Also, if you have experience with a module I would be glad if you could share it.

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, I decided to give another chance to img2pdf. I'm using the following code from the official [GitHub README](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf/blob/master/README.md):

```
import img2pdf
pdf_bytes = img2pdf('test.jpg', dpi=150)
```

But it throws an exception:
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Do someone knows how to use img2pdf as a module to several images?`

Comment: You say that you have tried `img2pdf`. Try a bit more and come up with some script. If you get any error then we will help you.

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm trying to use this code from the GitHub description: `import img2pdf
pdf_bytes = img2pdf('test.jpg', dpi=150)` , but it throws an exception: `'module' object is not callable` . any idea?

Comment: Yes that's what take a few hours and try to get some code. Once you fell that you cannot go further, edit the question with that code. Somewone will surely answer :)

Comment: is there any documentation for img2pdf ? please do share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the GitHub code suggests to me that this module is callable. It's possible that's a mistake in the readme; they have meant for the example to use the `convert` function. Try this instead:

```
import img2pdf
pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(('test.jpg',), dpi=150, x=None, y=None)
```

In [the source code](https://github.com/josch/img2pdf/blob/master/src/img2pdf.py), this function requires positional arguments `x` and `y`:

```
def convert(images, dpi, x, y, title=None, author=None, creator=None, producer=None,
            creationdate=None, moddate=None, subject=None, keywords=None,
            colorspace=None, verbose=False):
```

But as long as you provide the `dpi` argument, it's set up with a default case that makes it look (to me, at least) like both `x` and `y` were intended to be optional arguments:

```
    if not x and not y:
        pdf_x, pdf_y = 72.0*width/ndpi[0], 72.0*height/ndpi[1]
```

The package you got on PIP isn't necessarily identical to the code on GitHub, though. You could try it without supplying `x` and `y` as arguments to `convert` as well—or even better, find the source file on your own machine and check it out yourself.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the detailed answer! I tried to use `convert`, but it throws me really weird exception: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "createpdf.py", line 2, in <module>
    pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert('example.jpg', dpi=150, x=None, y=None)
  File "C:\Python279\lib\site-packages\img2pdf.py", line 209, in convert
    with open(imfilename, "rb") as im:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'e'` The image file exists, and the script + image are both in the same directory. Do you have any clue what is wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at the source again, yes: the first argument is expected to be an iterable. Strings in Python are iterables over their chars; you should pass it in a list or tuple instead (see updated answer).

Comment: Thanks you very much! But again, there's another problem that I think you cant fix- the output PDF file is damaged. Adobe Acrobat cant open it, but Foxit Reader can- and it shows the images [weirdly](http://i.imgur.com/pW61opy.png). I have no idea hy it happens, and I tried a few JPG images from Google and it still not working. Probably its a problem with PIL but I dont have the knowledge to fix it. Anyway, thank you for your help!! @AirThomas